# Start up Siri loop

Tags: ios, login

I've just updated the OS on my iPad mini 4. Now when trying to start with the button and fingerprint it goes straight to Siri and will not let me past Siri. If I push the button again goes to password screen. It will accept a typed password, and the fingerprint goes back to Siri.

It now locked me out for 15 minutes, and Siri will not start. Says no internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 10, you need to click the button to unlock the device. However, **don't hold down** the home button, just click it once. If you wish Touch ID to read your fingerprint, after clicking and releasing the click, keep resting your finger on the sensor.